# A question about of normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group. Is it true to say that "If $M\lhd G$, then $M$ is containing a minimal normal subgroup of $G$"?

Comment: If you don't condition anymore, then the trivial subgroup $\;\{1\}\,$ is *always* **the** minimal normal subgroup of any group.

Comment: Even though one requires the non-triviality, the answer is still yes. As $M$ itself contains a normal subgroup $M$, and the group is finite, hence possessing only finitely many subgroups, there must be a minimal one contained in $M$.

Comment: The correct statement would be "If $\{e \} < M \lhd G$, then $M$ is containing a minimal normal subgroup of $G$"

Answer (score 4):

The [standard definition of **minimal normal subgroup**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristically_simple_group) requires it to be non-trivial. Just check any relevant article in the group theory literature, like this random sample

- Ataei, Mohammad Javad. Minimal normal subgroups and semisimplicity condition. Int. J. Algebra 6 (2012), no. 1-4, 179-183.
- Dobson, Edward; Malnič, Aleksander; Marušič, Dragan; Nowitz, Lewis A. Minimal normal subgroups of transitive permutation groups of square-free degree. Discrete Math. 307 (2007), no. 3-5, 373-385.
- Bamberg, John; Praeger, Cheryl E. Finite permutation groups with a transitive minimal normal subgroup. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 89 (2004), no. 1, 71-103.

So, yes, in case of a finite group, a *non-trivial* normal subgroup $M$ always contains a minimal normal subgroup, just consider the set of non-trivial subgroups of $M$ which are normal in $G$. This set is finite, and non-empty, as it contains at least $M$, so it will have a minimal element, with respect to order, or inclusion.

In the infinite case this fails, just think of $\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any subgroup contains e. The subgroup {e} is a normal subgroup of any group and its only subgroup is {e}. Therefore it is minimal.

Comment: Well, $\;\{e\}\lhd\{e\}\;$ , so yes: the trivial subgroup contains a minimal ( **the** minimal) normal subgroup of any group...

Comment: wait, what is a minimal subgroup?LOL

Comment: **The** minimal subgroup of any group is always the trivial subgroup. I suppose the OP meant to aks about minimal *non-trivial* normal subgroup...but who knows?

Comment: but any non trvial subgroup also contains {e}. So therefore it is true

Comment: What is true? You lost me...

Comment: what the Op asked

Comment: Yes, what the OP asked about is always trivially true, even dropping the normal requirement.